# .Net 7 Minimal API - using .Where causing error

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I am doing some learning on .Net 7 and minimal API's

I am simply trying to return a list of all timesheets within a payperiod. but I get the following error

> Error CS1061  'Task<List>' does not contain a definition for
> 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first
> argument of type 'Task<List>' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
group.MapGet("/Payperiod/{payperiod}", async Task<Results<Ok<Timesheet>, NotFound>> (string payperiod, TimesheetAPIContext db) =>
    {
        return await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync().Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod))
            is Timesheet model
                ? TypedResults.Ok(model)
                : TypedResults.NotFound();
    })
    .WithName("GetTimesheetByPayPeriod")
    .WithOpenApi();
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here and how I should be writing this endpoint?

Cheers

Comment: Try (await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync()), you are doing Where on the Task before it is awaited.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should put the where() before ToListAsync(), simply, you can think all linq's meothd end with Async is final method, you should not chain invoke after it.
Second, you can not use the `Is Timesheet` to check where it is empty. you should use the Any().
the modifed code as below:

```
group.MapGet("/Payperiod/{payperiod}", async Task<Results<Ok<Timesheet>, NotFound>> (string payperiod, TimesheetAPIContext db) =>
    {
        var ret = await db.Timesheet.Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod)).ToListAsync();
        
        return ret.Any() 
                ? TypedResults.Ok(ret)
                : TypedResults.NotFound();
    })
    .WithName("GetTimesheetByPayPeriod")
    .WithOpenApi();
```

Comment: Thank you - This hasn't worked for me either.  Any() only returns a bool.
I want to return a 200 and a json list of timesheets and if there are none returned return a 404

 I feel I am missing something fundamental and feel a bit stupid right now.

Comment: @cramar when ret.Any() have value, it will return Ok(ret),  it will be a 200 and a json list of timesheets. you can try it.

Comment: @cramar Its an `Ternary Operator` it evaluates the `.Any()` if `true` it retuns the `?` aka `TypedResults.Ok(ret)` else the NotFound. But should you haven't an `<List<TimeSheet>>` in you method decleration? As `Task<Results<Ok<List<Timesheet>>`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it looks like (looking at your responses in comments) you are writing asynchronous code without knowing how it works. Please correct me if I got that wrong.

The thing is, asynchronous programming can be very complex if you have no idea of what you are doing.
Have a look at these sources to understand asynchronous programming:

- https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-async-programming-in-csharp/
- https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/4240/your-ultimate-async-await-tutorial-in-c/introduction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model

Now let's take a look at your code:

```
group.MapGet("/Payperiod/{payperiod}", async Task<Results<Ok<Timesheet>, NotFound>> (string payperiod, TimesheetAPIContext db) =>
    {
        return await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync().Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod))
            is Timesheet model
                ? TypedResults.Ok(model)
                : TypedResults.NotFound();
    })
    .WithName("GetTimesheetByPayPeriod")
    .WithOpenApi();
```

This line `return await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync().Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod))` is where the problem exists.
You are trying to retrieve the Timesheet table from the database, then asynchronously convert it to a `List<>` and filter the result.

The problem is that you should wait for the `ToListAsync()` task to finish before you can filter the result with `Where`.

This is one example of how you can fix it (mind the extra parentheses):

```
group.MapGet("/Payperiod/{payperiod}", async Task<Results<Ok<Timesheet>, NotFound>> (string payperiod, TimesheetAPIContext db) =>
    {
        return (await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync()).Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod))
            is Timesheet model
                ? TypedResults.Ok(model)
                : TypedResults.NotFound();
    })
    .WithName("GetTimesheetByPayPeriod")
    .WithOpenApi();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.Where` on a Task you need to first call `.Result` to actually get a List.

```
return await db.Timesheet.ToListAsync().Result.Where(t => t.Contains(payperiod))
            is Timesheet model
                ? TypedResults.Ok(model)
                : TypedResults.NotFound();
```

Comment: Thank you - but this hasn't worked for me.

IEnumerable<Timesheet>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Timesheet>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: in that case you will need to use a `.ToList()` after the `.Result` to convert it from an `IEnumerable<Timesheet>` to a `List<Timesheet>`.

Comment: like this: `db.Timesheet.ToListAsync().Result.ToList().Where(...)`